# Magento Free shipping ONLY on standard shipping

Tags: magento

I am having no problems setting up free shipping for certain items with shopping cart rules. However, it being Christmas time, I want to offer free shipping on standard shipping, but leave Express shipping at it's regular price. When I setup the shopping cart rule to give free shipping to a specific item it automatically reduces every flat rate shipping method to $0. Is there a way around this?

Comment: could you provide condition of the the rule that you made?

Comment: Sure. Ok so I gave the rule a name, no coupon code, $0 fixed discount, Free shipping for shipment with matching names & only apply to item with matching SKU.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the screenshot it might help you.. here regular is the shipping code for Standard shipping and i have added extra condition if order amount is more than $100.

[image: 1st Image]
[image: 2nd Image]
[image: 3rd Image]

Best of luck, Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: First off, thank you very much for taking the time to help me out. However, this sort of works and I tested this earlier today. Yes, it does give free shipping on the final step of the checkout process. However, if you go all the way to the last step of checkout, and then decide oh wait i forgot something, and then re-checkout, you'll see the discount is applied to all shipping methods (atleast on my end). Also, if you use this method and then try paypal express, it still gives free shipping on all methods?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/WebShopApps/extension/604/webshopapps-matrixrate--the-original-multiple-table-rate-solution--certified-bug-free please check this extension

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution.

**The Problem**: Multistore website with multiple shipping method: flatrate, matrixrate. In some store the free shipping rule should be applied only to matrixrate and not flatrate, in some others should be applied to flatrate.

**The Solution**: Use the rule like explaned here with whatever condition but the shipping method one. Then create a module that extend the Flatrate model (or the one witch shouldn't be affected by the rule) for prevent to apply the shipping rule according to a configuration specific for website.

More info here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/173063/4647